# Update Sql Table from datagridview c#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, sql-update

Hi I have a datagriview and I add it a data source of a sql table

```
 this.fletera_facturasTableAdapter.Fill(this.indarDataSet2.fletera_facturas);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'indarDataSet1.fletera_facturas' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
```

and in the event of **keypres**  i want to update the changes to sql if the user press "Enter" key on cell
this:

```
 private void update_sql(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            fletera_facturasTableAdapter.Update(indarDataSet2.fletera_facturas);
        }
    }
```

i don't get any error but the sql table doesn't update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution I just need to add this line

```
 private void update_sql(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        fletera_facturasTableAdapter.Update(indarDataSet2.fletera_facturas);
        **indarDataSet2.fletera_facturas.AcceptChanges();**
    }
}
```